# How to install nested npm packages with postinstall or single npm command

Tags: npm, npm-install

I have a package I wish to publish to NPM that also contains a demo directory like below:

```
.
+-- demo
|   +-- src
|   |   +-- main.js
|   +-- package.json
+-- src
|   +-- main.js
+-- package.json
```

My question is I would like user to be able to run `npm i` and `npm start` to start up the development server but I don't know how to run `npm i` in the demo directory at the same time as the top level one. Using `"postinstall": "cd demo && npm i"` puts me in an infinite loop of installs.

**EDIT1:**
My demo package.json depends on the parent module using `"parent-module": "file:../"`. I believe this is the cause but how can i solve it. I don't want to use a custom `npm install` command.

**EDIT2:**
Even with the parent dependency removed, it still attempts to go into an infinite loop but it now errors as the nested demo folders are not there anymore.

Comment: I just tried this, it works fine for me. Perhaps you can post the contents of your package.json files?

Comment: @RyanZim I think I have missed out an integral piece of information which I have added to my questions. My demo package.json depends on the parent module.

Comment: getting the same issue, run script for install is `"install": "npm i"`, run script for post install is `"postinstall": cd client && npm i`, this falls into infinite loop of installations. I am on Linux system

Answer (score 2):

For anyone still looking for this, you can add this script in the root `package.json`:

```json
"scripts": {
  "postinstall": "npm install --ignore-scripts -C ./demo"
```

the `--ignore-scripts` option will prevent this from running recursively

Comment: Very clever, and exactly what I was after.

Answer (score 0):

Running `npm install` in a `postinstall` script will not work because this means that the postinstall script recursively calls itself: postinstall calls install, which in turn triggers postinstall (and so on forever) as defined in the npm script lifecycle rules.